# CLI Calculator that can solve built-in formulas and basic equations

Tags: java, beginner, console, calculator

I am just a java beginner — so this program is very basic. It works as intended but I think it's a bit too repetitive and it probably uses more resources than intended. Also, I cannot run this from jar, because I have no idea how to use swing.

```
      import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Formula {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean logout = false;
    while (!logout) {
        Scanner strCommand = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Action ([continue], logout) ?");
        String command = strCommand.nextLine();
        if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("logout")) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        Scanner numIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner strIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
        double anum, bnum, cnum, dnum;
        String formType, equ;

        System.out.println("Choose an option:");
        System.out.println("Surface Area | Volume | Calculator");
        formType = strIn.nextLine();

        switch (formType.toLowerCase()) {
        case "calculator":
            System.out.println("Please input the First number:");
            anum = numIn.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please input the Second number:");
            bnum = numIn.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Please input on of the following operations:");
            System.out.println("+");
            System.out.println("-");
            System.out.println("*");
            System.out.println("/");
            equ = strIn.nextLine();

            switch (equ.toLowerCase()) {
            case "+":
                System.out.println("The answer is:");
                System.out.println(anum + bnum);
                break;

            case "-":
                System.out.println("The answer is:");
                System.out.println(anum - bnum);
                break;

            case "*":
                System.out.println("The answer is:");
                System.out.println(anum * bnum);
                break;

            case "/":
                System.out.println("The answer is:");
                System.out.println(anum / bnum);
                break;
            }
            break;

        case "volume":
            System.out.println("Choose one of the following formulas:");
            System.out.println("Cube");
            System.out.println("Rectangular Prism");
            System.out.println("Cylinder");
            System.out.println("Pyramid");
            System.out.println("Cone");
            System.out.println("Sphere");
            equ = choice.nextLine();

            switch (equ.toLowerCase()) {
            case "cube":
                System.out.println("Please input the side length of a cube:");
                anum = numIn.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("The Volume of the Cube is:");
                System.out.println(Math.pow(anum, 3));
                break;

            case "rectangular prism":
                System.out.println("Please input the length of the Rectangular Prism:");
                anum = numIn.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Please input the width of the Rectangular Prism:");
                bnum = numIn.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Please input the height of the Rectangular Prism:");
                cnum = numIn.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("The volume of the Rectangular Prism is:");
                System.out.println(anum * bnum * cnum);
                break;

            case "cylinder":
                System.out.println("Please input the Radius of the Cylinder's Base:");
                anum = numIn.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Please input the Height of the Cylinder:");
                bnum = numIn.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("The Volume of the Cylinder is:");
                System.out.println(Math.PI * Math.pow(anum, 2) * bnum);
                break;

            case "pyramid":
                System.out.println("Please input Side 1 of the Pyramid's Base:");
                anum = numIn.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Please input Side 2 of the Pyramid's Base:");
                bnum = numIn.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Please input the Height of the Pyramid:");
                cnum = numIn.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("The Pyramid's Volume is:");
                System.out.println((1 / 3) * (anum * bnum) * cnum);
                break;

            case "cone":
                System.out.println("Please input the Radius of the Base:");
                anum = numIn.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Please input the Height of the Cone:");
                bnum = numIn.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("The Volume of the Cone is:");
                System.out.println((1 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(anum, 2) * bnum);
                break;

            case "sphere":
                System.out.println("Please input the Radius of the Sphere:");
                anum = numIn.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("The Volume of the Sphere is:");
                System.out.println((4 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(anum, 3));
                break;
            }
            break;

        case "surface area":
            System.out.println("Choose one of the following formulas:");
            System.out.println("Cube");
            System.out.println("Rectangular Prism");
            System.out.println("Sphere");
            System.out.println("Cylinder");
            equ = choice.nextLine();

            switch (equ.toLowerCase()) {
            case "cube":
                System.out.println("Please input the side length of a cube: ");
                anum = numIn.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("The surface area of the cube is:");
                System.out.println(anum * anum * 6);
                break;

            case "rectangular prism":
                System.out.println("Side A:");
                anum = numIn.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Side B:");
                bnum = numIn.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Side C:");
                cnum = numIn.nextDouble();
                System.out.println((2 * anum * bnum) + (2 * bnum * cnum) + (2 * anum * cnum));
                break;

            case "sphere":
                System.out.println("Input the radius of the sphere:");
                anum = numIn.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("The surface area of the Sphere is:");
                System.out.println(4 * Math.PI * (anum * anum));
                break;

            case "cylinder":
                System.out.println("Input the Radius:");
                anum = numIn.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Input the Height:");
                bnum = numIn.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("The surface area of the Cylinder is:");
                System.out.println((2 * Math.PI * (anum * anum)) * (2 * Math.PI * anum * bnum));
                break;
            }
            break;


        }

    }

  }

}
```

AS you can see, I use a LOT of System.out.printl(); in the code. I am guessing that that is very Efficient. I do not know much — I just know the basics, so I cannot think of any more efficient way to write code. I still cannot wrap my head around sub-Classes, but I think I am getting the hang of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm just going to cover one point, *single-responsibility principle* (known in the trade as SRP).

SRP dictates, pretty self-sufficiently, that each method should have *one and only one responsibility*. That responsibility *could* include multiple sub-parts, but the method itself should have *one job to do*.

Your method has several, let's go over them:

- Loop until the user states to logout
- Give the user a main-menu option
- Give the user a sub-option
- Gather input for calculations
- Perform calculations
- Gather result of calculations
- Print result of calculations

That's a lot of stuff, not to mention, you have three major categories of calculations as well.

So let's break that down. We first need to create a main 'pump' loop.

> ```
> boolean logout = false;
> while (!logout) {
>     Scanner strCommand = new Scanner(System.in);
>
>     System.out.println("Action ([continue], logout) ?");
>     String command = strCommand.nextLine();
>     if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("logout")) {
>         System.exit(0);
>     }
> ```

You don't actually set `logout`, but you could. Make this the last thing that happens and we can use the `logout` variable to indicate when to stop.

```
boolean logout = false;
while (!logout) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    ...

    System.out.println("Action ([continue], logout) ?");
    String command = scanner.nextLine();
    if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("logout")) {
        logout = true;
    }
}
```

So this is *one* responsibility: create a main message pump / loop until the user wants to 'logout'. Now what do we do with our sub-responsibilities?

Well, we need to give the user the main menu. For that we'll create a method:

```
public void mainMenu(Scanner scanner) {

}
```

And our loop will call the `mainMenu`:

```
boolean logout = false;
while (!logout) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    mainMenu(scanner);

    System.out.println("Action ([continue], logout) ?");
    String command = scanner.nextLine();
    if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("logout")) {
        logout = true;
    }
}
```

Great! Now we have to do the main menu things.

```
public void mainMenu(Scanner scanner) {
    System.out.println("Choose an option:");
    System.out.println("Surface Area | Volume | Calculator");
    formType = scanner.nextLine();

    switch (formType.toLowerCase()) {
    case "calculator":
        ...
        break;
    case "volume":
        ...
        break;
    case "surface area":
        ...
        break;
    }
}
```

So each of these `case` options can call *yet another function* that prints the sub menu.

```
private void calculatorMenu(Scanner scanner) {
    System.out.println("Please input the First number:");
    double anum = scanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please input the Second number:");
    double bnum = scanner.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Please input on of the following operations:");
    System.out.println("+");
    System.out.println("-");
    System.out.println("*");
    System.out.println("/");
    String equ = scanner.nextLine();

    switch (equ.toLowerCase()) {
    case "+":
        System.out.println("The answer is:");
        System.out.println(anum + bnum);
        break;

    case "-":
        System.out.println("The answer is:");
        System.out.println(anum - bnum);
        break;

    case "*":
        System.out.println("The answer is:");
        System.out.println(anum * bnum);
        break;

    case "/":
        System.out.println("The answer is:");
        System.out.println(anum / bnum);
        break;
    }
    break;
}
```

Now our `case "calculator"` just calls `calculatorMenu(scanner);`.

You *should* be able to see where this is going, we're not *completely* in SRP mode yet, but we're close enough *for a beginner*. Eventually I would expect that you would create a `Calculator` class, and go from there, but I don't want to throw too many things at you at once. :)

Comment: This is a lot of help! Thank you very much. There's one thing that I do not fully understand though. What does "mainMenu(scanner);" do?

Comment: @Ribchinski It calls the `mainMenu` method and passes the `scanner` variable as the `scanner` argument. Do note that the `scanner` in `mainMenu(scanner)` and the `scanner` in `mainMenu(Scanner scanner)` *do not* need to be the same name. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Comment: Because the calculator menu method is private, I cannot call it from the "choice" class. I am kinda new at calling classes from other classes, so I kinda need some help.

Comment: @Ribchinski The easiest fix for that is to make it `public`, but I would recommend extracting out your print logic and menu logic, essentially the `Calculator.menu()` method should return what the menu *should* look like, then it should be printed in the `main` method. This way the `Calculator` class doesn't need to worry about the printing.